# Looking for a specific C++ technique

Tags: c++

I don't know if this fits the StackOverflow questions, but here it is...

I have a class that has a matrix to represent it's transformations in 3D space, and it has a bool to check whether this matrix needs to be updated or not (since it seems to be an expensive operation).

Basically, I calculate the final matrix from the: matrix4x4 center * matrix4x4 rotation * matrix4x4 position.

This class have methods to set the center/rotation/position, so each time a new value is set, I set the bool to update to true, and the next time the program requests the final matrix, I know if I have to recalculate it or not.

Now, the problem is that I'm creating the objects that use this class and I want it to work as the interface for whoever might be programming with it.
So instead of having the programmer type:

```
Object* myObject = new Object();
myObject->orientation.SetCenter(x1, y1, z1);
myObject->orientation.SetPosition(x, y, z);
myObject->orientation.SetRotation(angle, axis);
```

I'd like to make it so they can type:

```
Object* myObject = new Object();
myObject->position.x = x;
myObject->position.y = y;
myObject->rotation.angle = angle;
```

With **position** and **rotation** being vector classes with float values.
But just by changing these values I can't figure how to tell if the transformation matrix should be updated or not.

Is there a good and unexpensive (performance is important for me) way to deal with this?

Comment: How about adding a `recalculate()` method the programmer can call whenever they finish making a set of related changes? As a bonus, this avoids an incompletely-updated matrix being calculated if a series of update operations is still in progress when the matrix is next requested.

Comment: You are looking for property accessors.  Looks like a field, actually executes a method.  Not the C++ way.

Comment: Just `Object myObject;` please, while we're discussing C++ style. that doesn't leak memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some good answers in these previous questions:

- [Having Public properties in c++ class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559900/having-public-properties-in-c-class)
- [C#-like properties in native C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225087/c-like-properties-in-native-c)
- [Portability of Native C++ properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772480/portability-of-native-c-properties)
- [Property like features in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079052/property-like-features-in-c)
- [dot property access in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394428/dot-property-access-in-c)